# How to position svg and to hide and show svg based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/drc83/vn3tbovu/19/

css:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: lato;
  color: #fff;
  background: #999;
  padding: 55px 30px;
}


.checkbox-styled {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
}
.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"] + span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #27ae60;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
  -moz-transition: background 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: background 0.1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.1s ease-in;
  transition: background 0.1s ease-in;
}
.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"] + span:hover {
  background: #1e8449;
}
.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: block;
  content: ":)";
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"] + span.sad:before {
  content: ":(";
}
.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
  background: #145b32;
}



.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

jquery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){ 
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
    $('p').toggleClass('sad');
});
```

html:

```
<div>
  <label class="checkbox-styled">
    <input type="checkbox" name="happy" value="happy"/>
    <span>Happy</span>
    <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/><path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/></svg>
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="checkbox-styled">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sad" value="sad" />
    <span class="sad">Sad</span>
  </label> 
</div>
```

It has a customised checkbox, I also have an svg animated checkmark. Firstly I need help to place the checkmark centered under the words happy and sad within the box. Secondly I want the checkmark to only animate once a selection is made under the appropriate selection. Thirdly once the animation completes the circle every so slightly moves once the animation is complete, any help with these would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, can you clarify a bit what do you mean to place it centered under the words? can you show a mockup of what u want with the placement

Comment: Is this close? https://jsfiddle.net/evqy155f/6/

Answer (score 1):

sorry I never used jquery, so my code is js and also pretty rough (no caching etc)

1. Animation resetting - I think there an article on css-tricks that explains ways to do it: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

So you can use same approach

2. CSS placements is something I did very roughly through absolute positioning as I am not sure what is your full context.

See the code:

```js
function animationReset() {
  document.getElementById('checkmark').classList.remove('checkmark');
  document.getElementById('checkmark__circle').classList.remove('checkmark__circle');
  document.getElementById('checkmark__check').classList.remove('checkmark__check');
  void document.getElementById("mainDIV").offsetWidth;
  document.getElementById('checkmark').classList.add('checkmark');
  document.getElementById('checkmark__circle').classList.add('checkmark__circle');
  document.getElementById('checkmark__check').classList.add('checkmark__check');
}

function positionChange(source) {
  if (source === "happy") {
    document.getElementById('checkmark').attributes.style.value = "display: inline; position: absolute; left: 115px; top: 180px;"
  } else {
    document.getElementById('checkmark').attributes.style.value = "display: inline; position: absolute; left: 315px; top: 180px;"
  }

}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
  $(this).prop("checked", true);
  // anim reset:
  animationReset();
  positionChange(this.name)
  $('p').toggleClass('sad');
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: lato;
  color: #fff;
  background: #999;
  padding: 55px 30px;
}

.checkbox-styled {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
}

.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"]+span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #27ae60;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
  -moz-transition: background 0.1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: background 0.1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.1s ease-in;
  transition: background 0.1s ease-in;
}

.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"]+span:hover {
  background: #1e8449;
}

.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"]+span:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: block;
  content: ":)";
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"]+span.sad:before {
  content: ":(";
}

.checkbox-styled input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span {
  background: #145b32;
}

.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scale {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDIV">
  <label class="checkbox-styled">
  <input type="checkbox" name="happy" value="happy"/>
  <span>Happy</span>
</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="checkbox-styled">
  <input type="checkbox" name="sad" value="sad" />
  <span class="sad">Sad</span>
</label>
</div>
<svg style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 115px; top: 180px;" id="checkmark" class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><circle id="checkmark__circle" class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/><path id="checkmark__check" class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/></svg>
```